# Knex not picking up ENV variables

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, knex.js

I'm trying to configure Knex to use environmental variables to choose the database to use. For whatever reason, it seems very finicky and quick to forget the setting. The first invocation works, and the second does not:

```
% NODE_ENV=test npm run knex:migrate # No semicolon

> repo@0.1.0 knex:migrate
> npm run knex migrate:latest


> repo@0.1.0 knex
> ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js "migrate:latest"

Using environment: test # Uses the test environment
Already up to date
```

Add a semicolon between commands and it doesn't work:

```
% NODE_ENV=test; npm run knex:migrate # Semicolon

> repo@0.1.0 knex:migrate
> npm run knex migrate:latest


> repo@0.1.0 knex
> ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js "migrate:latest"

Using environment: development # Uses the (default) dev environment
Already up to date
```

And yet...

```
% echo $NODE_ENV
test
```

The variable is still set, but Knex is ignoring it. However, if I set `NODE_ENV=test` in my `.env` file, it sticks. If I try to pass `--env test` to the CLI, it never works. Does anyone have insight?

Edit: If I call `npx knex migrate:latest --env test` it gets picked up, but it still doesn't pick up the `NODE_ENV` values:

```
% npx knex migrate:latest --env test # This works
Using environment: test
Already up to date

% echo $NODE_ENV
test

% npx knex migrate:latest # This doesn't                            
Using environment: development
Already up to date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with knex but the way the shell you are using works.

`NODE_ENV=test` is only defining a 'local' variable that by default is not forwarded to sub processes.

`export NODE_ENV=test` would make it available to all sub-processes

`NODE_ENV=test npm run knex:migrate` would run `npm run knex:migrate` with `NODE_ENV=test`